# Remove whitespace between div and other div containing image

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I can't get two divs to align perfectly on top of each other. Whatever I try, there remains some white space between them.

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4334uss/2/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div id="slider" class="row">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img id="scroller1" class="scroller" src="https://www.pexels.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/pexels-photo-18-1280x420.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>           

<main>
    <div id="Project" class="row">
        <div class="singlecol">
            <h1>Header1</h1>
            <h2>Header2</h2>
            <p class="blocktext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #383433;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

h1 {
    color: #383433;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
} 

h2 {
    color: #843a32;
} 

.slideshow-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

img.scroller {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
}

.singlecol {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours, deleting every line of css possible, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've also checked earlier questions on this topic, but none of what I try resolves the problem.

Would appreciate some fresh eyes :-)

Comment: The fiddle link does not work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o4334uss/

Comment: Check This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4334uss/7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the img element `display:block`, as it inherits the `inline` from its parents.

```
img.scroller {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqL84Lmx/

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Also in your fiddle example the whitespace is still present. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: seems to work indeed, however when I add it to my css file it doesn't seem to change anything. Would you care to take a look to the full file? Maybe some other css is interfering

Comment: There's no need. If it works here, it should work, unless something is overshadowing the display property in your context. So try making it a "display: block !important;

Comment: Still not working, guess I need to remove every css element again to see what causes the issue. Will vote up for correct answer, thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
.mySlides.fade {
    display: grid !important;
}
```

to css :)

https://jsfiddle.net/o4334uss/6/

Comment: this doesn't work (I've only taken the essential code out for the example). In my real framework it's a slider and the "display: grid" code makes all image appear straight below each other. I do see how it could work with a single image tho (as in your fiddle). Do you have any other suggestions?